# "large" dataset crashes Gridview when Scrolling. Win32 error

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I keep running into a bug that is starting to infuriate me and I have no idea how to solve it.
I have a grouped gridview with perhaps 500 - 1000 detail items over about 30 groups. (All done in C#) When grabbing the scroll bar with the mouse and quickly movethrough the list I (sooner or later) get, a

> Unhandled exception at 0x0fda84de in myapp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access
>   violation reading location 0x006d006f.

The debugger will throw me into an assembly page that is hieroglyphs to me.
I am populating the gridview from an api call to another server, which does make fairly drastic changes to my observable collection feeding the list, however this is all loaded prior to me ever getting the exception

I have no idea if this is just some sort of out of memory thing, or a bug, etc. I am aware of this:

[blog post](http://mikaelkoskinen.net/winrt-xaml-gridview-performance-problems-on-windows-rt-tablets/)

But this doesn't seem to fit the bill; I am not using caching, nor does it occur on navigate. I also am not ok with inline group headers. PLENTY of apps (Music, netflix, etc). use the gridview grouped and don't suffer this problem.
I am about at the end of my robes on this one.

If I new what the error WAS I could do a better job of tracking down the source!

thanks everyone,

Comment: What happens if your using paging or lower amount of rows ? does it matters ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what kind of gridview are you using, but if you are experiencing this only when the rows count is big and not when its a small number you should consider not using .net gridviews due to their slow performance.

A quick google search would give you an amount of grids for each technology you need.

If you are Using the .net "datagridview" try using this dll in your project, I know it helped me a lot, and I made some effort in finding it ...

http://speedy.sh/dHhX4/SpeedUpDGV.rar

after you add the dll to your references just use it like this :

```
YourGridviewName.SpeedUpThisGridView(true);
```

You should also consider paging or sending the information in some async way and then reloading it...

But that's only if the case is handling big amount of information

Hope I helped.